# React Routing works in local machine but not Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, react-router

React/react router/heroku question here (it is probably heroku where it is failing).

I am following this wonderful tutorial: https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d#.y77yjte2j
and everything works up to the point where I post it to heroku and I try to navigate to https://appname.herokuapp.com/about and I get a 404 Not Found/nginx error. Of course, per the tutorial it is supposed to display an About page.

Bottomline: **React router is not working on heroku and I can't figure out why**.

I have tried modifying my `server/app.js` file as suggested in this: [React routes are not working in facebook's create-react-app build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789425/react-routes-are-not-working-in-facebooks-create-react-app-build)

```
// server/app.js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

console.log('hi from /src/server.js')
// Setup logger
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms'));

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {

  console.log('hi from app.get.about')
  console.log(req)
  console.log(res)
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {

  console.log('hi from app.get')
  console.log(req)
  console.log(res)
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});


module.exports = app;
```

but it doesnt work nor does it log anything at all in the console:

```
2017-01-20T21:03:47.438140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/boot`
2017-01-20T21:03:49.540005+00:00 app[web.1]: Injecting runtime env into /app/build/static/js/main.242e967b.js (from .profile.d/inject_react_app_env.sh)
2017-01-20T21:03:49.695317+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting log redirection...
2017-01-20T21:03:49.695899+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx...
2017-01-20T21:03:51.108255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-20T21:04:22.720627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com request_id=fb8bc13b-f6b5-47bc-8330-443f28e211df fwd="132.147.73.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=627
2017-01-20T21:04:22.746761+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.158.165.5 - - [20/Jan/2017:21:04:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 386 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
2017-01-20T21:04:23.076521+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.158.165.5 - - [20/Jan/2017:21:04:23 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.242e967b.js HTTP/1.1" 200 62263 "https://sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
2017-01-20T21:04:23.056416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.242e967b.js" host=sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com request_id=436d5ce5-ee39-4ab7-9e12-f5871e0fd552 fwd="132.147.73.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=62540
2017-01-20T21:04:23.745285+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css" host=sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com request_id=80438aaa-58c4-456e-8df9-7a29e49bc4ba fwd="132.147.73.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=560
2017-01-20T21:04:23.766676+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.158.165.5 - - [20/Jan/2017:21:04:23 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.9a0fe4f1.css HTTP/1.1" 200 301 "https://sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
2017-01-20T21:04:24.044940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg" host=sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com request_id=bcbc1906-3b90-4f13-a700-f432f79c725d fwd="132.147.73.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=2902
2017-01-20T21:04:24.065013+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.158.165.5 - - [20/Jan/2017:21:04:24 +0000] "GET /static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 2671 "https://sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
2017-01-20T21:04:26.264631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=sentieoapp1.herokuapp.com request_id=0caef324-9268-4ebb-a3f5-0fb047100893 fwd="132.147.73.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=403
2017-01-20T21:04:26.284717+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.158.165.5 - - [20/Jan/2017:21:04:26 +0000] "GET /about HTTP/1.1" 404 191 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
```

and this is where I'm stuck. I am familiar with Express and have gotten it to work on heroku before but this is a whole nother level of nightmare. I understand that this is not server side routing but rather react doing routing from within a single index.html page. But if I can get it to work on my local machine why does it not work on Heroku?

Comment: Guessing you mean that client-side (dynamic) routing is not working for you. Heroku is expecting server-side (static) routing when you visit a URL, so you must reconfigure the static routes to first load the "index.html" file (which is the `\\` endpoint by default). Solutions presented below.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I actually came across this post first before 3 hours of searching through react-router and heroku documentation. For swyx, and anyone else having the same problem, I'll outline the minimum of what you need to do to get this working.

**router.js** - (Obviously change AppSplash and AppDemo to your components)

```
export default <Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={AppSplash}/>
    <Route path="demo" component={AppDemo}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
static propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
}

render() {
  const { children } = this.props
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App
```

Create a new file in the root of your home directory and name it **static.json**. Put this into it.

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Push to heroku again. The routes should work this time.

**Explanation:**

You need to modify Heroku's default webpack, otherwise the service gets confused with how to handle the client-side routing. Essentially what static.json does. The rest is just the correct way to handle the routing according to the 'react-router' documentation.

Comment: wow, thanks HarshMarshmallow. this may actually make create-react-app usable for me now that i can put react router on it. I had completely abandoned this route and sought out other fully deployable boilerplates since I asked this question. marking you correct without testing

Comment: Does that solution work for GitHub pages? I've been blocked for two days...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045867/how-to-deploy-cra-to-github-pages-using-react-router?noredirect=1#comment85096685_49045867

Comment: For me this doesn't work, I've opened a new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852877/static-json-not-working-for-reactjs-routes-and-heroku

Comment: Just FYI, this does not work for me at all. Adding `static.json` has zero effect. dhahn's answer predictably worked, since it makes sure express serves the index file for react-router URL that don't match any express route.

Answer (score 28):

## How to fix client-side routing errors (Heroku 404 errors):

#### React Browser Router

If you're using [React Browser Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter), as an *npm* module with *create-react-app*, then the solution (which works for me) is to create a `static.json` file (within the same directory as `package.json`).

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

**Here is why this solution works:**

*Create-react-app* is for the most part a *Node.Js* server which serves client-side *React*. The `public` static directory is mapped to the `/` endpoint, and visiting this endpoint from a browser will download the `index.html` webpage. This webpage in turn loads the React components. And because *React Browser Router* is a React component, the routes are loaded dynamically after visiting the `/` endpoint. In other words, before the `index.html` webpage is loaded all our *React Browser Router* routes will result in 404 errors on Heroku. To resolve this issue, a `static.json` file can be used to map any endpoints with the following pattern `/**` to the `index.html` file, which in turn will load React Browser Router and correctly load the react components for that route.

**From an Apache HTTP server:**

Likewise, on an Apache HTTP server creating an `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory, will remap all endpoints that match `/**` to the `index.html` file.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**More resources**

Also read the "Deployment" section of the `create-react-app` README, which has a ton of good information on how to reconfigure the server to use client-side routing.

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

#### React Static Router

Lastly, *React Router* offers a static router, [React Static Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/StaticRouter), which can be used with the "react-dom/server" *npm* module on a Node.js server, to render *JSX* server-side, and doesn't need `static.json` or `.htaccess` reconfiguration.

Comment: This solved my problem thank you for the information

Comment: @tfmontague Does that solution work for GitHub pages? I've been blocked for two days...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045867/how-to-deploy-cra-to-github-pages-using-react-router?noredirect=1#comment85096685_49045867

Comment: For IIS/Windows/Azure server, this tut is a good help. https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321

Comment: @NullisTrue - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom - might have a solution?

Comment: @AnimeshSingh - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#azure-https-azuremicrosoftcom - also shares a couple other links for automatic deployment to Azure

Answer (score 4):

### Try this:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  let url = path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html');
  if (!url.startsWith('/app/')) // since we're on local windows
    url = url.substring(1);
  res.sendFile(url);
});
```

Worked for me when I put into server.js.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after making sure that I do not return `index.html` in certain cases, like when requesting `transformed.js`. I wrote a more detailed explanation as a separate post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Webpack+Express Solution

#### TL;DR

Use `res.sendFile` but don't forget to also return `transformed.js` and other static files.

#### Explanations

I've been testing some of the answers on this thread, but none of them really worked for the following setup:

- I am using webpack (-dev-server) on my local machine.
- In production (on Heroku), I simply serve the webpack build output with a static express server. Something along the lines of `app.use(express.static('${__dirname}/build'));`.

This obviously does not work with a react router as `static` only returns actual files from the `build` folder (i.e. `index.html`) and will return 404's on any other url.

David Hahn's proposed solution to use `res.sendFile` pointed me to the right direction. However, the main issue with hijacking `GET *` is that the secondary request to `transformed.js` would also return `index.html`. After fixing the code to avoid this, I was able to get a working solution.

#### Code

Here's my `server.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var app = express();

// List of all the files that should be served as-is
let protected = ['transformed.js', 'main.css', 'favicon.ico']

app.get("*", (req, res) => {

  let path = req.params['0'].substring(1)

  if (protected.includes(path)) {
    // Return the actual file
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/build/${path}`);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, redirect to /build/index.html
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/build/index.html`);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

Happy to discuss what you think! I am not a React veteran yet so there might be a better way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a full day thinking the backend had the problem. After going through all the solutions for the backend and a thorough log inspection, realized it was the react App.js.

I changed each

```
Axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/createOrder`, {

})
```

to

```
Axios.post(`/createOrder`, {

})
```

and it worked!