# Problem with routing on react app on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have problem with my app on heroku 
https://quiet-meadow-74770.herokuapp.com/

When I click register and refresh page, I have a error.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Routing works in locally but not Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723509/react-routing-works-in-locally-but-not-heroku)