# React router is not working client-side. How do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I'm using React Browser Router, as an npm module (react-router-dom) with create-react-app. Routing works fine on local but not after deployment. 
**When pressing a link I'm not taken to the desired location (for example /start). The page can not be found.**

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013926/7672369) tip but it still doesn't work.

I'm not using Heroku and I don't know if I should be.

Here are some code snippets from my react App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Components/Home.jsx";
import Billigast from "./Components/Billigast";
import NoMatch from "./Components/NoMatch";
import Start from "./Components/Start";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
            <Route path="/start" component={Start} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

static.json:

```
{
  "root": "/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

I've tried several `"root":` locations. My index.html file **is in** root.

Here is one of the linked pages:

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Form from "./Form";

const Start = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Start;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Please be specific.

Comment: Sorry, body updated.

Comment: React Router changes location internally using history.push() and showing / hiding components. Getting "The page cannot be found" sounds like the browser actually follows the link. Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was **not** importing react-router-dom NavLink properly. I was importing NavLink, but from reactstrap.

**Fix** (in NavBar component)**:**

```
import { NavLink as RouterNavLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

since both reactstrap and react-router-dom uses the same name (NavLink) and i wanted to use both due to design.

I then wrapped the RouterNavLink within the NavLink like so:

```
<NavLink>
  <RouterNavLink to="/start">Start</RouterNavLink>
</NavLink>
```

It's not surprising that it did not work since i wsen't even importing correctly.

Also, i did not need the static.json file.