# static.json not working for ReactJS routes and Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router

In theory this should work, adding at the `/` folder the file `/static.json` that makes everything go to the React `index.html`.

(related)

[React Routing works in local machine but not Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku)

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#configuration

In my case it doesn't work, I get a `Cannot GET /hello` instead of receiving the index.html. Surprisingly, if I go directly to `/index.html` I get the page but no route is activated.

**What is happening and how can I fix it?**

> UPDATE: tried without luck `/static.jason` `/src/static.jason` `/client/static.jason` `/client/src/static.jason`

`/static.json`

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

`/client/src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FileUpload from './FileUpload';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div><FileUpload /></div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`/client/src/FileUpload.mjs`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class TextFileReader extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Router>
    <div>
     <Route path="/heyyo" render={() => <span>heyyo</span>} />
     <Route exact path="/" render={() => <div>resting</div>} />
     <Route path="/what" render={() => <div>what</div>} />
      NO ROUTES HERE
    </div>
   </Router>
  )
 }
}

export default TextFileReader;
```

Comment: where did u put ur static.json? with ur client or server package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, re-reading better this [React Routing works in local machine but not Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku) I've added this line to my Express

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  let url = path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html');
  if (!url.startsWith('/app/')) // we're on local windows
    url = url.substring(1);
  res.sendFile(url);
});
```

And once deployed to Heroku, it works :)

Comment: Not working Here is the link - [click](https://home-services-housedeck.herokuapp.com/). Can you provide another solution i tried static.json and this method too.