# "Cannot GET /" on refresh on deployed site with custom domain name

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

My routes work fine on my local server, and on my heroku deployed app...not with the custom domain though. Loading the site works fine, along with each route initially.

On refresh of any routes aside from the root, I get a "cannot GET /" response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres an example of my routes...

// App.js

```
<Router>
  <div className="App"></div> 
     <NavBar/>
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: You may need to add `static.json`, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku