# Heroku url routes can only be reached programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

Sorry if this question is vague but I really don't know what code to present.

I have a Heroku webpage which is running fine.  I am using reach-router to navigate from one page to another on button clicks:  `<button onClick={() => navigate('/intro')}>Click</button>`.  When I do this the url changes appropriately and my content is visible.  However if I type in the exact same url I get an error saying `Cannot GET /intro`. This error even happens if I use the button click to navigate and then reload the page.

It's my understanding that `app.use(express.static('build'));` will serve my static files.

So why can I visit pages if I start at my root url and navigate from there but I can't enter a url and travel to that page?

The website is live here https://build-a-wedding.herokuapp.com/

Adding more details on my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const sessionMiddleware = require('./modules/session-middleware');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(sessionMiddleware);

app.use(cors());

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

const users = require('./routes/users.router');
const dataFetch = require('./routes/data.router');
const venues = require('./routes/venues.router');

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/location', dataFetch);
// app.use('/', auth);
app.use('/venues', venues);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

When I navigate programmatically here is what i see for my sources[image]

When I type in the same URL here is the source tree[image]

Comment: Means server not configured for the virtual directories. Have you used any heroku buildpacks? Is your react app based on create-react-app? If it is installing buildpack for it should fix issue

Comment: @charlietfl I used npx create-react-app.  I don't think I am using any buildpacks. How do I install those?

Comment: For prior to deploy : https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack . You can also install after deploy, I think from dashboard but has been a  long time so read buildpack docs

Comment: looks like that works thanks!

Comment: Curious...did you do it from dashboard or CLI?

Comment: I did it from the CLI.  I have initiate Heroku Apps from the Dashboard before and never ran into this issue.

Comment: At least was easy fix. Things like that can be frustrating when not sure what to do and have to spend hours researching

Comment: Oh for sure. Glad you could help :)

Comment: Now that I look at this more I don't think it will work for me because I need a Node server for my database connection.

Comment: So should be able to configure express or other framework to server create-react-app and serve as api

Comment: @charlietfl I have app.use(express.static('build'). shouldn't this serve my static files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Routing works in local machine but not Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `static.json` file at the root of your React project with the following content:

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

[This question is possibly duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772411/react-routing-works-in-local-machine-but-not-heroku)

Comment: I have that already.  Is it not being referenced properly?

Comment: Is it at the same level of `package.json` file and pushed to heroku?

Comment: It is at the same level as `package.json`, I am assuming it is pushed to heroku since it isn't in my `.gitignore`

Comment: I am using `@reach/router` for my front end navigation.  I'm not sure if that could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your express app are listening to these routes and sending response to them.
Example:

```
app.get('/intro', function (req, res) {
  res.send(pathToPage);
});
```

Comment: I can try this.  Shouldn't app.use(express.static('build')) handle this?  Also what is the pathToPage in this example?

Comment: This has nothing to do with client side routing

Comment: Alright, so instead of navigating to '/intro' try navigating to 'intro.html' I think this is the final solution :).